# Why my view events are not firing?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

Here's my CoffeeScript code:

```
$(document).ready ->
  SearchView = Backbone.View.extend
    tagName: "form"
    className: "search"
    events: {
      "click label":"search"
    }
    search: ->
      console.log("HERE")

  searchView = new SearchView()
```

And here's my HTML:

```
%form#search.search
  %label
    Search
  %input
```

But clicking the form is not triggering any events. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand how `tagName` and `className` work. When you set these:

```
tagName: "form"
className: "search"
```

That just means that you'll have `<form class=​"search">​</form>​` in `@el`. Those settings don't bind your view to what the `form.search` selector matches and you never add `@el` to the DOM so your events don't end up bound to anything at all.

If you want to use `tagName` and `className` then you'll want a `render` to flesh out your form:

```
render: ->
    $(@el).append('<label>Search</label><input>')
    @
```

And then you'd call `render` and add `el` to the DOM with something like this:

```
searchView = new SearchView()
$('div').append(searchView.render().el) # 'div' is just an example of course
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ubqqE/

If you wanted to bind to existing HTML then you could use `el` instead of `tagName` and `className` like this:

```
SearchView = Backbone.View.extend
    el: '#search'
    #...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/FfDg6/